# How to target list item hover state inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is kind of tricky. I'm using this js effect that changes my navigation color as you scroll through different sections. So when you scroll past the section with the class "green" it changes the hover border color of my nav. This is usually how it's done

```
.midnightHeader.green a:hover {
        border: 3px solid #2b5999;
}
```

the problem is, I have other links in my header which I don't want to apply this to. So I only want to style the links inside the unordered list items, but the following code doesn't work.

```
.midnightHeader.green nav ul li a:hover {
        border: 3px solid #2b5999;
}
```

Basically would I style the "nav ul li a:hover" inside ".midnightHeader.green"

[Please have a look at midnight.js it explains how this works](http://aerolab.github.io/midnight.js/)

Can anyone help me work this one? Thanks

Comment: Add your html code please.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question should contain a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example, [here's how](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: you could try `:not` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not

Comment: `would I style the "nav ul li a:hover" inside ".div-name"`, no in css .something is a class which you can add to an element like this `<div class="something"></div>` what you want to do here is give the div an unique id and select it with `div#yourId nav ul li a:hover{}`

Comment: Please check this link:-https://css-tricks.com/hover-on-everything-but/ & https://css-tricks.com/examples/HoverEverythingBut/